# How to transform Model-View-Presenter architecture to WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mvp, restful-architecture

Right now we are working with a classic ASP.NET WebForms project with a Model-View-Presenter (MVP) architecture. Our company wants to move towards a common way to share data between applications based on RESTful APIs. Therefore we are looking for ways to transform our MVP architecture to a WebAPI project. There is quite a lot of code in the presenters and it will take a long time to move the code to another layer. We are looking for a good way to transform to an architecture based on WebAPI's.

Right now there is a strong binding between the .aspx pages with code behind and the presenter layer. One idea is to place one more layer in between the Presenter and View. That way we can replace the old .aspx with a more modern page. E.g.,

> Model 
>        Presenter
> Old view | WebAPI layer
>                 New view

Is this a good idea? We hope to hear your input regarding this plan. What are the pitfalls? Are there better ideas? Any experiences?

<sub>Perhaps this question is not suitable for stackoverflow since it is more a request for discussion. Suggestions for a better place to ask are welcome if so.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a [Presenter, or Supervising Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) **doesn't map well into the REST model, because they have both state and actions** associated with them.

A WebAPI layer is actually going to map much more closely with your **repository layer** than it will your presenter.

The Presenter, instead of existing on the server, would exist on the client.

My advice is not to go down this path of trying to mix the two together like this. **There will always be an enormous impedance mismatch**, and you will end up with an API that isn't very useful to other clients. Especially if you want to move to more modern Mobile/Web application architectures.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your answer. Our presenters perform "presenter" tasks like `Initializing the view`, but also perform others tasks that are more `repository`-, `data access`- and `business logic`-like, like checking if the input is valid and calling managers that store data in the database. The latter methods seem to be possible to use in an API. Then we can move the presentation aspects to the view.     

Am I right? What other path would be advisable?

Comment: @user2609980 - Yes, you are correct that validation is something that is going to be part of the API layer, but the semantics are very HTTP specific. I just don't know how much value there will be in trying to re-use your Presenters code in the Web API world. At least not directly from the presenter itself. I would recommend making a clean break, and simply deprecating the MVP stuff. I realize this is easier said than done, but the two won't really mix well.

Comment: @user2609980 - Know I don't make this recommendation lightly. I do it as someone who actually has [quite a bit of MVP experience](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A11702+mvp).

Comment: Thanks, they indeed make extensive use of SessionData. That will not be available.